# jQuery DataTables - Splice selected from array via index - Always removing only first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to remove items from a jQuery DataTable and then also splice the selected items from the array for which the table shows data for.

I can successfully remove the items from the table, but the splice function I've used on the array to remove selected row indexes is always only removing the first item in the array, and not those selected.

JS:

```
$('#deleteInvoiceItems').on('click', function() {

    var row = $(itemsTable).find('tr.selected');

    var rowIndex = row.prop('rowIndex');

    invoiceItems.splice(rowIndex);
    itemsTable.rows('.selected').remove().draw();

    calcInvoiceTotals();
})
```

Comment: You'll need to get the index of each item in the array and splice from the array. You mentioned multiple rows, loop through those rows and get the index of each and splice.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done by finding all of the selected tr's and then getting the index 'rowIndex' datatable property below

Comment: Well right, but you havent gotten the index of that row item from the array yet. Is the array an array of html row elements? if so itll be easy to remove each item, otherwise youll have to find by a property name.

Comment: No, it's a json array that i've just attached to the invoiceItems variable